# Rails, Capistrano and DelayedJob: make a deploy with an active task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, delayed-job

I'm running an application, into a production server, that needs DelayedJob to perform background tasks. Those tasks take a long time to execute.

My deploy.rb has something like this:

```
desc "Start workers"
task :start_workers do
  run "cd #{release_path} && RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n 2 start"
end

desc "Stop workers"
task :stop_workers do
  run "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop"
end

before "deploy", "stop_workers"
after "deploy:start", "start_workers"
```

Now, let's assume there's a background job. I need to update the application. Running the deploy, will cause the delayed job to stop and the task will be interrupted.

How can I deploy without stopping the background jobs?

Answer (score 0):

`delayed_job` will wait for the current job to finish processing (unless you really force it to stop).

So, you have a couple of options I think. You can wait for the current job to finish before you continue the deployment. I'm pretty sure that that is what your code will currently do.

Alternatively you can let delayed_job continue to process its current job in the background. I.e. tell delayed_job to stop the queue but don't both to pause the deployment whilst it does so. It will continue to run with the code from your previous deployment. This is more risky, I would suggest, as your deployment process might include database schema changes with migrations which might cause problems for the currently running job.

Lastly you could code the long running jobs so that they can cope with an interruption. `delayed_job` will rerun the job if it fails.

It sounds to me like you want the second option but I think unless the jobs run for many minutes I'd opt for just waiting for delayed job to process the current job.